# Checking if user input is in a list of objects

Tags: python, list, input

I'm making a text adventure and trying to allow the player to pick up items from a room. I'm doing this by having the room have an `items` attribute which is a list of objects from an items module. I attempt to check if the user's input is in the list, however even if they're identical it says it's not in it.

world.py:

```
class ItemTile(MapTile):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.items = [items.Bread(), items.Herbs()]
        super().__init__(x, y)
```

items.py:

```
class Bread(Consumeable):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "Bread"
        self.healing_value = 15
        self.value = 20
```

game.py:

```
elif hasattr(room, "items") and 'take' in action:
    player.pick_up(action)
```

player.py:

```
 def pick_up(self, action):
        room = world.tile_at(self.x, self.y)
        item = action[5:]
        item = item.title()
        print(item, room.items[0])
        if item in room.items:
            self.inventory.append(item)
            room.items.remove(item)
            print('You pick up the {}'.format(item))
        else:
            print("You see no such thing.")
```

for example if I input `'take bread'` (Just printing to show they're the same):

```
Bread Bread
You see no such thing.
```

Also my IDE says that under the consumables class `self.name` is unresolved.

Comment: The string `'Bread'` is **not** the same thing as the `Bread` instance in the list, even if they have the same representation. Consider a dictionary mapping string names to actual objects. Also it seems like bread should be an *instance* of `Consumeable`, not a *subclass*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Can you check my dictionary code in the edit above? I think I'm still not really comprehending the representation of different elements. Sorry :/ And about the subclasses, I was following a tutorial - I didnt know any better XD

Comment: I would suggest you write a new question with a proper [mcve] of your new attempt, building on what the answers below have taught you. If you change the question, you invalidate the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a `name` attribute you best compare against this onw:

```
if item.lower() in [i.name.lower() for i in room.items]:
```

Explanation: `[i.name.lower() for i in room.items]` is a "list comprehension" and builds up a list constisting of `name` attributes of all rooms in `room.items`. I added `lower()` because you most probably don't want that case matters.

Comment: Given the OPs evident experience level you should at least include the phrase *"list comprehension"* so they can search for it.

Comment: @hansaplast Thanks for your help. Sorry, this is the first program I've made and it was following a tutorial too. When i go to remove the item from room.items, how would i reference the list item inputted by the user? Clearly the string is not the same as the instance, as I have learnt.

Answer (score 0):

In your last method you set the value for item twice, right after each other:

```
    item = action[5:]
    item = item.title()
```

Title will replace whatever value "action[5:]" was. But this is beside the point. You have a list of (presumably) objects which might actually look like this [, ] and you try to compare these values with "Bread", which is most likely not going to be in there at all.

The objects have a hashed value when they are created, so as to distinguish them from other objects with the same "name".

In your item list you have 2 instances and up front there is almost no way of telling what the hashed values for them will be, let alone you comparing them.

Comment: Yeahh, that makes sense ahah. Thanks! I just didn't really know how to do it.

Comment: Nearly there! When creating this dictionary you fill it with instances of items. So the result when you ran this dict would be something like {'bread': <object:bread>} (etc for the others). This means that now when you want to search said dictionary you can call the key. The key however is case-sensitive (lookup Hashed value). In the background Python used a formula to hash "bread" into a unique key. This means you need to find the EXACT match. I.e. "bread" instead of "Bread". Call the dict with key "bread" should get you the object for bread.

Comment: Also might I suggest using PDB (Python debugger). This allows you to inspect code when running it. Just put "import pdb" on top and pdb.set_trace() on the line you want to intercept. I know this has helped me a ton (and still does) when I want to know exactly what is going on.

Comment: Sounds helpful, I'll give it a shot thanks! Sighh it's still not processing as a match though, despite them both being the same object... Ahhhh D:

Comment: I hope you got it working now. Also note that making an instance of the same class twice using the exact same parameters does NOT make it the "same" object. So long as you are asking Python to compare 2 objects it will most likely tell you they are not identical.